# How do I simplify/straighten faces if Shade Smooth and Edge Split failed

Tags: rendering, edges, smooth

im new to Blender and ran into this problem: [image: edit mode]

[image: object mode]

The inside is a mess, its supposed to be smooth and the edges around the top have to be clean

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

1. best way is to redraw the holes yourself|
2. You can use a remesh modifier with a high resolution and a smooth modifier to clean up the edges.
3. In Cycles use a "bevel node"  to smooth sharp edges quickly.
4. actually the conical part is most messy, you can delete it and connect the bottom cylinder with the top cylinder by using a "loft" or "bridge" with the  "Loop tools" add-on to get rid of most of the triangles.